# Directory structure of angular application, in case of role implementation

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angular, angular-material

What would be the best directory structure of angular application, in case we have to implement three roles, suppose admin, supervisor,user. Normally we have files in feature directory having feature module. But would be case for three roles as three of them has different views.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to make 3 modules (admin, supervisor, user module) under the app module.
And define the routes to load the child modules like

```
var routes=[
  { path: 'user', canLoad: [ AuthGuard ], loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule' },
  { path: 'supervisor', canLoad: [ AuthGuard ], loadChildren: './supervisor/supervisor.module#SupervisorModule' },
  { path: 'admin', canLoad: [ AuthGuard ], loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' }
]
```

And define AuthGuard and override "CanLoad" function.
That function is called when the route is loaded so before activating the component,
using this function, you can check if the user can enter to this module or not and can redirect to the sign page.

So making independent modules for each permission and implementing canLoad function on auth guard, you can solve this problme.

Answer (score 0):

Given that info and based on just roles only you can create folders for each role, and managing everything through the **Auth Guard**.

The auth guard is an angular route guard that's used to prevent unauthorized users from accessing restricted routes, it does this by implementing the [**CanActivate**](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) interface which allows the guard to decide if a route can be activated with the canActivate() method. If the method returns true the route is activated (allowed to proceed), otherwise if the method returns false the route is blocked.

The auth guard uses the authentication service to check if the user is logged in, if they are logged in it checks if their role is authorized to access the requested route. If they are logged in and authorized the canActivate() method reutrns true, otherwise it returns false and redirects the user to the login page.

Angular route guards are attached to routes in the router config, this auth guard is used in app.routing.ts to protect the home page and admin page routes.

Comment: Thanks for detailed elaboration.. In brief, I should create admin,supervisor, user directories under feature directory which is standard directory under src directory while for shared services I would use core directory right??

Comment: Yes it's one way to do it.